# FORTH include vs load?

Tags: io, forth, gforth

`INCLUDE` obvious does file IO. But I'm confused how it works with `LOAD`. What does `INCLUDE` do without a `LOAD`? From the book,

- `INCLUDE xxx  ( -- )`

  > Load the text file xxx (compiles or executes).
- `LOAD ( n -- )`

  > Loads a disk block (compiles or executes).

Comment: `INCLUDE` loads a file, whil `LOAD` loads a disk block

Answer (score 5):

Historically, FORTH was a whole operating system, and read/wrote disk blocks directly for simplicity (one block was 1 KiB text, displayed/listed/handled as 16 lines of 64 characters). That is what `LOAD` handles.

Nowadays source is handled in regular files,  managed by an underlying complex operating system. Thus `INCLUDE`.